# Move text up on hover without moving its container

Tags: html, css

I have searched for solutions around the internet, and everyone suggested using `position: relative` and `top: -2px` or `margin-top: -2px`.

And both solutions indeed move the text inside the container, but also move the container itself up/down (or increases the height?):

[image: Example]

An example using the first solution:

```
a {
    position: relative;
}
a:hover {
    top: -2px;
}
```

How would I go on about fixing this? I've been trying different ideas (for example, having containers in containers with hidden overflows and so on), but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want ?

Comment: your gif shows text moving up and container getting bigger

Comment: The question says what OP wants. They do *not* want the container to get bigger.

Comment: still the question is blur, as the container is not resizing, it's moving up by `top: -2px`

Comment: I feel like you're intentionally acting like you don't understand what OP wants to achieve. It's pretty easy to understand that the container is not supposed to move.

Comment: In the second paragraph I say that the container moves up/down or resizes. I guess I didn't notice it when I typed out the title, because the hovered button and background color were so similar that it looked like the button just became bigger. I'll change the title.

Comment: Suggestion work just fine, you just need to hover its parent, e.g. .parent:hover > a {...}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `padding` to change the text position and give the parent element a fixed height. Then, on hover, lower the `padding-top` value, which will push the text to the top.

```css
.wrap {
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}

a {
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

a:hover {
  padding-top: 10px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Using padding on both `a` and `a:hover` is really clever, I would have never thought of that! It does seem to make the text move down when not hovered (probably some other issue, as it is fine in your example), but it doesn't really matter as it's just two pixels.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved with just padding, for example:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: 11pt/1.5em sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  padding: 2em 3em;
  background: lightslategray;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: padding 0.15s, background 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  padding-top: calc(2em - 2px);
  background: darkslategray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<a href="#">First</a>
<a href="#">Second</a>
<a href="#">Third</a>
</nav>
```

Or, alternatively, using nested containers and `transform`:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: 11pt/1.5em sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  padding: 2em 3em;
  background: lightslategray;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

a div {
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}

a:hover {
  background: darkslategray;
}

a:hover div {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
<a href="#"><div>First</div></a>
<a href="#"><div>Second</div></a>
<a href="#"><div>Third</div></a>
</nav>
```

Using `transform` (and `opacity`) for transition/animation should have [some performance benefits](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/), but i doubt it will be significant or noticeable for this simple transition…